# Java File List: NPE while using for loop

Tags: java, linux, nullpointerexception, filepath

I've written simple java code to display file list in Linux to use it for FTP program using TCP(I'm going step by step, using all features). I'm posting this question after googling for about half an hour.

```
import java.io.*;
class FileList
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
String dirname="/home/vaibhav/Test";
File f1=new File(dirname);
String sl[]=f1.list();
System.out.print(f1.list()+"......."+sl.length+" files found.");
for(int i=0;i<sl.length;i++)
{ 
System.out.print(sl[i]+" ");
}      
}
}
```

Output:

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~/Java$ javac FileList.java
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~/Java$ java FileList
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FileList.main(FileList.java:10)
```

My Directories Test and Java contents:

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~$ cd /home/vaibhav/Test
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~/Test$ dir
1  2
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~/Test$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 vaibhav vaibhav 4096 Jan 18 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 vaibhav vaibhav 4096 Jan 18 16:50 ..
-rw-rw-rw-  1 vaibhav vaibhav    0 Jan 18 15:04 1
-rw-rw-rw-  1 vaibhav vaibhav    0 Jan 18 15:04 2
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~/Test$ cd
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~$ cd /home/vaibhav/Java
vaibhav@vaibhav-VirtualBox:~/Java$ ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 vaibhav vaibhav 4096 Jan 18 16:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 vaibhav vaibhav 4096 Jan 18 16:50 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 vaibhav vaibhav  990 Jan 18 16:52 FileList.class
-rw-r--r--  1 vaibhav vaibhav  477 Jan 18 16:52 FileList.java
-rw-r--r--  1 vaibhav vaibhav  487 Jan 18 16:52 FileList.java~
```

**When I changed String dirname to /home/vaibhav/Java which is pwd too, program executed well.**

What was the issue?
Thank you.

Comment: for loop line is line 10

Comment: Mmmh ... I doubt this, why we don't get output from `print`. I think sl is null. What gives `f1.isDirectory()`.

Comment: no, sl isn't null. I added 2 files to it, before running code.

Comment: Is it related with pwd?

Answer (score 0):

Better to try this:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I tried that too before posting here. But one post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11643057/2642938 said that using list() is better than using listFiles(). My main question is "When I changed String dirname to /home/vaibhav/Java which is pwd too, program executed well."

Comment: can you explain more clearly what is your requirement exactly @VAL

Comment: To display file lists from .../Test dir. @SanthoshKumar544

Comment: so what ever the answer i posted definitely displays file lists from your desired path and also including directories @VAL

Comment: yeah, I don't know why it didn't display it before that! That's why I posted it here. Now after changing dirname multiple times its working well.

Comment: then provide the code before changing the dirname so that i can give a clarity for your confusion and can say what the exact pblm was before

Comment: I just changed dirname to .../Java (which is pwd) replacing .../Test